Jupyter Lab Dark Theme
How to change jupyter lab' theme please, so it has the same theme as
"! jt -t onedork -fs 12 -ofs 12 -T"
in jupyter notebook?
I can install it, but it never works!
Any idea why? Thank you.
N.B. The black color of the built in dark theme is so depressing, if I can just change it that would be great.
Thank you :-)
I installed jupyter themes after updating, then the onedork theme never worked again.

It's JupyterLab, one word. And this post title needs work.


The old Jupyter Theme is not compatible with Jupyter 7.
Two possible ways, if you don't like the default built-in dark theme:
1- Download dark theme extension (blue), for Chrome, so many of them.
2- Try:
pip install jupyter_theme_editor
For more info about how it works.
3- Please google "jupyter lab / notebook dark theme respiratory github".
Good luck :-)


You don't need the "yet" in the first sentence. The tech JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ are built on is very different and so the old theme won't be updatable to work with Jupyter Notebook 7+. Plus, a dark theme comes built in now.

Update:
pip install jupyter_theme_editor
caused some conflicts with Chrome, especially if you customized it to dark theme.
The best so far is 'Jupyter Darkside Theme" it def do the job.
Thank you, and best of luck :-)
